# Need help on Managed-Beta Packages

Tags: managed-package, developer-edition

From one of the  dev orgs, my organisation has created a managed package and it is currently in Managed-Beta state.Due to some reasons, we are now working on to add some more components(Apex classes - extensions particularly- **lets call it Ext1**) to the same package.These apex classes are referring to some other class (**lets call it REFCLass**) which is a part of the managed-beta package.Currently, Ext1 is **NOT** a part of the managed package.

I wrote a test class for Ext1(**lets call it testExt1**).Now to achieve code coverage,when testExt1 is run, and we check debug logs , we don't see the code of REFClass- it shows as **Entering managed Package**.Why is the code not visible in debug even though, we are in the same dev org, where the package is created.Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

did you add the test class to your managed package?
Also - you can set the level of debug log to be shown through Setup->Logs->Debug Logs

Comment: we already have a test class in place that is why we are working on the coverage part.The issue is that while debugging the code, i am not able to see the actual code on which i am targeting the code coverage.It shows as "Entering Managed Package" .I have also set the debug logs that is why i am able to tell you abt it

Comment: Are you running these test from within the org that the package is developed?

Comment: YEs ....in the same dev org, from where the package is developed.Actually the test class is written for a class which is not a part of the package but this class is referencing another class which is a part of the package

Comment: can you post the classes?